# run ant with the NDK without setting the ndk.dir in the local.properties

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk

I've been trying to compile a NDK project using ant (`ant release`), but to make this possible I need to set the local.properties with the following line:

```
ndk.dir=/{my-path}/android/android-ndk-r9
```

I would like to add this in my .bash_profile, but I tried with all this variables:

```
export ANDROID_NDK=/{my-path}/android/android-ndk-r9
export NDK=/{my-path}/android/android-ndk-r9
export NDK_ROOT=/{my-path}/android/android-ndk-r9
export NDK_PATH=/{my-path}/android/android-ndk-r9
export NDK_HOME=/{my-path}/android/android-ndk-r9
```

Any body knows how to fix that?

Comment: `~` points to your home folder, I think you need to stick `Development` after it.

Comment: That's not the problem. I've just edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: Did you append any of these variables to your `PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use

```
<exec executable="/{my-path}/android/android-ndk-r9/ndk-build.cmd" failonerror="true"/>
```

Another way, you can tell ant to use your variables by adding 
`<property environment="env" />` befor the exec line. 
for example set variable NDK_DIR and use it in the ant.properties file using "env.VAR" like

```
ndk.dir=${env.NDK_DIR}
```

or in my case:

```
<exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd" failonerror="true">
        <env key="ABI" value="armeabi-v7a"/>
    </exec>
```